# ImageView to display image from content of url takes more memory and app get crash

Tags: memory-leaks, uiimageview, uiimage, javax.imageio, crash

I Have a UIscrollView on which i am add Imageview(whose images displayed from the content of URL), the number of images are infinite. 
While scrolling the UIScrollview I a adding the UIImageView, But the App is getting crash because of low memory.

Can anyone help me out how to figure it out to overcome from this memory issue.

I had also tried to Profile the code where i can see is ImageIO Library takes the more memory while Scrolling.

Thanks in Advance, Anybody who knows the solution please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but using `didReceiveMemoryWarning` should be very helpful. When you will run low on memory, you should no longer allow to scroll more. Only other possibility might be removing images that are currently not visible.